# How to add menu item to right click menu in MS Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu, add-in, right-click

I am developing an add-in for `MS Project` in `Visual Studio` and I need a custom menu item in the `right click menu`. This will modify task data. I am using the following code to add a item:

```
 private void AddMenuItem(String param)
    {
        Office.MsoControlType menuItem =
            Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton;

        btn_editor =
            (Office.CommandBarButton)app.CommandBars[param].Controls.Add
            (menuItem, missing, missing, 1, true);

        btn_editor.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        btn_editor.Caption = "My Menu Item";
        btn_editor.Tag = "MyMenuItem";

        btn_editor.Click +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler
                (editor_Click);

    }
```

For String param I have used all the ComandBar names:

```
 CommandBars commandBars = (CommandBars)app.CommandBars;
  foreach (CommandBar cbar in commandBars)
        {
                AddMenuItem(cbar.Name);
        }
```

All it did, was to add the button in the Ribbon in Addins Tab. No button was added in the right click menu. Do you know another way to add in right click menu?

Comment: You want to look at ContextMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Context Menus in MS Project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/12/show-and-hide-context-menu-items-in-outlook-2010-norm-estabrook.aspx)
Take a look at this link to see if it will help

Here is another one that deals with Context Menus as well 
[Office Project adding Context Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723154%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This link will explain how to get at creating a Context Menu when you Right-Click the Mouse
[Creating a Context Menu when user Right-Clicks the Mouse](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/outlookdev/thread/ecd8b499-2f79-45f2-8ee0-d76e42ebbf9e)

Comment: I need this for adding a menu item to MS Project's right click menu. I cannot create a new contextMenu. It is not working on an add-in application.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d94a2222-6321-48b0-a653-363e467edb04 this link has some examples as well

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Ribbon XML API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691832(v=office.14)), this is an example for your case

## XML snippet

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
         <button id="MyMenuItem" label="My Menu Item" onAction="Button_Click" />
      </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

## Ribbon Code

```
public void Button_Click(Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl ctrl)
{
        switch (ctrl.Id)
        {
            case "MyMenuItem": System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MyMenuItem"); break;
        }
}
```